# How to use 2 parameters in the first parameter 'X ' of method LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My csv data is like this：

[image]

How to make the first parameter of the fit() into X1 and X2,not just X1.Because the data of Y is related to both X1 and X2.But I found the first parameter of the method fit() I can only pass one value.
Now my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

wine = pd.read_csv(r"D:/1.csv",sep=',')
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
X1 = wine.loc[:, ['importance']].as_matrix()
X2 = wine.loc[:, ['match']].as_matrix()
Y = wine['point'].as_matrix()
clf.fit(X1, Y)
print(clf.coef_,clf.intercept_,clf.score(X1, Y))
```

Output results：
[0.00402347]    92.58619838990552    0.04442683444842255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retain both of those columns as a single DataFrame.  Also, you don't need to use `as_matrix()`; sklearn can accept pandas objects as inputs.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

wine = pd.read_csv(r"D:/1.csv")  # sep=',' is default
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()

X = wine.drop('point', axis=1)
y = wine['point']
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.coef_, clf.intercept_, clf.score(X, y))
```

Above, `wine.drop('point', axis=1)` just says "give me a DataFrame including all columns *except* `point`.

If instead you wanted to specify those columns specifically (the results are the same in this case), you could do:

```
X = wine.loc[:, ['importance', 'match']]
```

Note that in this case, both `X` and `y` will be *views* to pieces of your original data.